# Batch to parse 3 variables and condense into 1 string

Tags: batch-file, cmd, findstr

I have about, 1k logs to pull and parse every night.

The idea is to run a findstr on all the logs with 1 of 4 keywords.  For example:

```
FINDSTR /s /i /c:"keyword" *.* >> Findstrresult.txt
```

Once that's ran I'll be able to see everything that had "keyword" in it and can parse it further.

This is where I'm stuck.  I can pull each variable that I want out by itself.  Example:

```
FOR /F "tokens=3 delims= " %%a in (Findstrresult.txt) do (
FOR /F %%b in ("%%a") do Echo %%~b >> Number.txt
)
```

This results in a list of 1k numbers.

Different tokens/delims would result in a list of 1k names.

Different tokens/delims would result in a list of 1k times.

Each in their own text file.

What I would like to do is pull them one at time then write them next to each other in one string into one text file like such:

Number, Name, Time

I'm so close.  I just need some advice.

Thank you.

Comment: Without knowing anything about your keywords logfile structure it's dificult to grep what you mean. Povide a [mcve] in your edited question best with some sample lines. I'd use Pwershell for this `sls * -Pattern 'keyword1|keyword2|keyword3' -context 2,2`

Answer (score 0):

```
(
FOR /F "delims= " %%a in (Findstrresult.txt) do (
 FOR /F "tokens=3 delims= " %%b in ("%%a") do ( 
  FOR /F "tokens,delims for name" %%n in ("%%a") do (
   FOR /F "tokens,delims for time" %%t in ("%%a") do (
    echo %%b,%%n,%%t
   )
  )
 )
)
)>combinedresult.txt
```

Read your file a line at a time into `%%a`, then parse `%%a` three ways. Nesting the `for /f`s keeps each metavariable in scope.

Enclosing the entire routine in parentheses allows the `echo` to be gathered and redirected to a new file. Append it to an existing file by using `>>` if you will.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will give this a try.  I appreciate you taking the time to comment.

Comment: I owe you a debt of gratitude.  Thank you so much you just expanded my knowledge tremendously.